# Updating Parent and Child Solr (5) Documents

Tags: solr

Given that I have indexed a `Parent Document` along with a number of `_childDocuments_`, what is the correct way to POST an update of that `Parent`? I understand that I need to resubmit `Parent` along with any `_childDocuments_`.

What I am having trouble with is that I create a database Record which triggers a call to index the item. (Using Laravel 5)

I then associate some additional data followed by firing a call to reindex that same item.

Rather than replacing the existing Solr Document with the updated version, it **adds another document with the same id** to the index. `<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>` is correctly set in `schema.xml`. I DO notice different `_version_` values.

Do I have to delete the `Parent` and any `_childDocuments_` BEFORE submitting revised document to the index?

NOTE: I am running on version `5.3.0-2015-06-16_01-18-34 1685690 - jenkins - 2015-06-15 21:25:19`

Here is the schema.xml minus comments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="example" version="1.5">
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

    <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

    <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_is" type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" />
    <dynamicField name="*_ss" type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_ls" type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_txt" type="text_general"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_en"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_bs" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_fs" type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_ds" type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>

    <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false" />

    <dynamicField name="*_dt"  type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_dts" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_p"  type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

    <dynamicField name="*_ti" type="tint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_tl" type="tlong"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_tf" type="tfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_td" type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_tdt" type="tdate"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

    <dynamicField name="*_c"   type="currency" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

    <dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="attr_*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

    <dynamicField name="random_*" type="random" />

    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />

    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>

    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>


    <fieldType name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>

    <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />

    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                    ignoreCase="true"
                    words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                    />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                    ignoreCase="true"
                    words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                    />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                    ignoreCase="true"
                    words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                    />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                    ignoreCase="true"
                    words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                    />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_en_splitting_tight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_general_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"
                    maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                    pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"
                    />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" multiValued="true" class="solr.StrField" />

    <fieldType name="point" class="solr.PointType" dimension="2" subFieldSuffix="_d"/>

    <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>

    <fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
               geo="true" distErrPct="0.025" maxDistErr="0.001" distanceUnits="kilometers" />

    <fieldType name="bbox" class="solr.BBoxField"
               geo="true" distanceUnits="kilometers" numberType="_bbox_coord" />
    <fieldType name="_bbox_coord" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" docValues="true" stored="false"/>

    <fieldType name="currency" class="solr.CurrencyField" precisionStep="8" defaultCurrency="USD" currencyConfig="currency.xml" />


    <fields>
        <field name="amount"             type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="area"               type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="attempted_at"       type="date"         indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="attempted_count"    type="int"          indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="attempted_how"      type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="attempted_dates"    type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" />
        <field name="block"              type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="body"               type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="building"           type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="city"               type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="community"          type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="condominium"        type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="contacted"          type="boolean"      indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="contacted_at"       type="date"         indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="contacted_by"       type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" />
        <field name="contacted_how"      type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="contacts"           type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" />
        <field name="continent"          type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" />
        <field name="country"            type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="created_at"         type="date"         indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="date_at"            type="date"         indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="description"        type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="directions"         type="text_en_splitting"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" />
        <field name="doc_type"           type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="feature_age"        type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="feature_color"      type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="feature_feature"    type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="feature_madeof"     type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="floor"              type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="geo_parent_id"      type="long"         indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="gmt"                type="int"          indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="initials"           type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="json"               type="string"       indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="key"                type="string"       indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="lang_id"            type="long"         indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="lang_keys"          type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"  />
        <field name="lang_mother_keys"   type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"  />
        <field name="latlon"             type="location"     indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="level"              type="int"          indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="name"               type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="nameInformal"       type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="neighborhood"       type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="owner_id"           type="long"         indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="parent_id"          type="long"         indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="par_key"            type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="path"               type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="publish"            type="boolean"      indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="publisher_initials" type="boolean"      indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="region"             type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="section"            type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="slug"               type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="status"             type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="subject"            type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="terrName"           type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="terrNameInformal"   type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="text"               type="text_general" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" />
        <field name="town"               type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="type"               type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="uid"                type="string"       indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="updated_at"         type="date"         indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="url"                type="string"       indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="weight"             type="int"          indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="zip"                type="string"       indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    </fields>

    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

    <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>


    <copyField source="area" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="body" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="building" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="city" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="condominium" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="continent" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="country" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="description" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="directions" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="feature_age" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="feature_color" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="feature_madeof" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="initials" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="name" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="nameInformal" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="neighborhood" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="publisher_initials" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="region" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="section" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="slug" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="subject" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="terrName" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="terrNameInformal" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="town" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="uid" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="url" dest="text"/>
    <copyField source="zip" dest="text"/>

</schema>
```

Comment: it would be good if you share the entire schema.xml here

Comment: After reindex, you end up with two documents or second one overriding the first?

Comment: I end up with two documents with the same `id` but different `_version_` values. The first has only the Parent Doc, then after the update it has the updated Parent along with `_childDocuments_`. I'm thinking that I MAY have to link child docs with Parent->id and then delete all docs with that id BEFORE resubmitting the update. Thanks for your input.

Comment: So what I have come up with in the meantime is that whenever I have `_childDocuments_` I set a childDoc field called `parent_doc_id` to equal the parent doc id. Then before I update/add a doc, I run a delete query like: `"<delete><query>(id:$id or parent_doc_id:$id)</query></delete>"`. This is resolving my immediate issue. I suspect though that this is a weak hack such as may be the case with race-conditions. So I look forward to any input.